# How to store this into SQLite Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, storage

Hey so I am new to using sql dbs, (mongodb / nosql fan here)... and I am trying to create an app on Android and store the information usually stored in a db for a website on the device, from what I understand I should use SQLite? (any objections let me know). When wanting to show info on a website would I be calling a get or can I just make the query calls right on the activity screen?

Lastly, this is an example of the information, and I wanted to know how I would store this as I heard that it only accepts integers, strings, and doubles?

Here is the db info needed to be stored:

```
Stored: {
        id: 2322d2ej2j2k, (unique)
        name: Animals, (unique)
        languages: [english, spanish],
        order: [a, b, c, d, e, f, ...],
        words: [{english: hello, spanish: hola}, {english: thanks, spanish: gracias},  ...],
        date_created: new Date()
        }
```

Also, for the order of letters, I want to be able to say that the order can be for letters in other languages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean with "wanting to show info on a wesbite would I be calling a get", as the SQLite database would be stored in a sandboxed location belonging to your app, you wouldn't be making HTTP requests but talking directly to the database.

I can suggest looking into : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper and extend it to create a wrapper for android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase for the most common CRUD operations.

While it's true that SQLite is more limited in data types (and querying operations) as full-on SQL, I find it more than adequate for most data operations. For complex Objects / nested values (like the "words"-property you describe in your question) I'd serialize these types of data into a String/JSON and reassemble it back into an actual Java Array/Object when reading it back from the database.

I prefer to think of records as entities in this sense and create a Model (extending your SQLiteOpenHelper implementation) which wraps the QSL CRUD functions to work with Java Objects and convert these to and from the data types supported by the SQLite database (i.e. create an abstraction layer such as "saveRecord" which accepts a Java value Object described the properties you posted in your question, but internally converts it to a more friendly format for storage, likewise a "getRecord" which returns a Java value Object created from the stored data).

Comment: Exactly ok, so no get type of requests need to be made. How do I go about serializing the data as json? is it best to just serialize the entire object as JSON and then deserializing... the issue I have to with the serialize approach is that I would want to query the db for words for example if someone searches "hello" to pull out words[0], without pulling out this whole document which will have 1000s of words stored in it...

Comment: Well, note that even with serialized text you could use a LIKE '%keyword%'-type statement to find the record by a keyword. But I'd like to stress that it depends on your database architecture what the right approach might be for the actual storing, for instance you could use comma separated values for the words instead of nested Objects within an Array... other cases could require a separate table joining individual words with the related records, etc.

Comment: Well that is what I am trying to figure out - here is a new question that makes thing simpler to answer, I will mark your answer right but I am looking for a more specific answer as I am new to this whole sql thing...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335332/how-to-store-an-object-nested-in-an-array-in-sqlite-android